# Exception Handling in RESTful Spring Boot Services

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, spring-mvc, exception

So I have various API endpoints defined in my `Spring Boot` services that throws various custom exceptions. But I am not able to make a distinction between *Checked* and *Unchecked* exceptions.

So should my custom exception be *Checked* or *Unchecked* exception?

Examples:

1. UserNotFoundException
2. EmailAlreadyExistsException
3. JWTTokenMalformedException
4. DatabaseNodeFailureException

These exceptions are parsed by Spring `ControllerAdvice`, converted to ResponseEntity and sent to client.

How would you define above custom created exceptions as *Checked* or *Unchecked*?
Also let me know if there is any thumb rule to decide if your exception should be *Checked* or *Unchecked*?

Answer (score 1):

You are good even if you have all your exceptions as `RuntimeException` since you delegate error response generation to `ControllerAdvice`.
Regardless of whether it is a RESTful Spring Boot Service or just another Java Application the premise to throw Checked or Unchecked Exceptions from a method largely remains on whether the caller MUST (Checked) or SHALL (Runtime) handle exception.

For example when calling

```
FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream("somefile.txt");
```

The constructor `FileInputStream(String fileName)` forces to handle the File not found exceptional scenario. Thus it throws a `FileNotFoundException` which is a checked exception and MUST be handled by the caller at the calling location itself.

Answer (score 1):

try defining all of them as unchecked
and define a method for each type of exception where you need specific handling with `@ExceptionHandler` in `ControllerAdvice`

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = { EmailAlreadyExistsException.class, UserAlreadyExistsException.class })
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handleAlreadyExistsException(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
    String yourErrMsg = "Some error desc.."
    List<String> errorMessages = List.of(yourErrMsg);
    HttpStatus httpStatusForTheError = HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST;
    return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>
(errorMessages, httpStatusForTheError);
}
```

and one final method as a catch all

```
@ExceptionHandler(value = RuntimeException.class)
protected ResponseEntity<Object> handle EmailAlreadyExistsException(RuntimeException ex, WebRequest request) {
    
    String yourErrMsg = "We are sorry, something went wrong."//don't disclose the stacktrace
    List<String> errorMessages = List.of(yourErrMsg);
    
    return new ResponseEntity<List<String>>
(errorMessages, HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
}
```

example from: https://www.baeldung.com/exception-handling-for-rest-with-spring

Answer (score 0):

> Also let me know if there is any thumb rule to decide if your
> exception should be Checked or Unchecked?

`Checked Exception` the compiler check and force you to handle the exception

`Unchecked Exception` the compiler does not warn you and you handle the exception by yourself

The rule you can adopt is the following

- if you are in a dependency case, where for instance you have to handle business rules throught many layers, then use `Checked Exception`. It will force you to handle your exception in top layers (service > controller)
- if you can't have the control on certain aspect of you application or architecture, such as access to a server or a file available in a location

Read [this](https://www.javatpoint.com/exception-handling-in-java) for more details.